# How to read text file in C++ with 4 character?

Tags: c++, file, input

I have following text file.

```
aaaaBBBBccccDDDDKKK
EEEEPPPPMMMMssssPPPP
AAAAEEEE
AAAAEEE
DDDDCCCC
```

And I have to read text file in c++ with divide four character.

and I want insert  the four length character into string in one array.

For example,
aaaa, BBBB cccc, DDDD, kkk, each word divided into array.
string WordArray[N][M]

```
WordArray[0][0] = "aaaa";
WordArray[0][1] = "BBBB";
WordArray[0][2] = "cccc";
WordArray[0][3] = "DDDD";
WordArray[0][4] = "KKK";

WordArray[1][0] = "EEEE";
WordArray[1][1] = "PPPP";
WordArray[1][2] = "MMMM";
WordArray[1][3] = "ssss";
WordArray[1][4] = "PPPP";
.
.
.

WordArray[4][0] = "DDDD";
WordArray[4][1] = "CCCC";
```

How can I read text in upper way?

I want to use `<fstream>`.

Comment: Do you have some incomplete or incorrect code for this?  We're not going to just write it for you.

Comment: You could use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) and the [`std::string::substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) function.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I didn't see your comment till after I posted my answer but, yeah. [I was actually hoping](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40869519/2642059) there was a more intelligent way to use `istream_iterator`s to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that you have successfully opened a file to: `ifstream pFILE` And let's say that your container is going to be defined as: `vector<vector<string>> WordArray` Then you can do something like this:

```
string line;

for(size_t word = 0U; pFILE; word = 0U) {
    getline(pFILE, line, '\n');
    WordArray.push_back(vector<string>()); 

    do {
        const size_t nextWord = line.find_first_not_of(line[word], word);

        WordArray.back().push_back(line.substr(word, nextWord - word));
        word = nextWord;
    } while(word != string::npos);
}
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/rJSI9i)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/

You could treat each block as 4 characters. Anyway you haven't specified even type of WordArray, so I assume it is flexy ( might be changed)