# Is There a Standard Algorithm to Copy Until?

Tags: c++, algorithm, copy, range, standard-library

I am using an `istream_iterator<char> it`, so I cannot iterate over the range in reverse (or iterate over it twice, without a great deal of hastle.)

I want to copy until a condition is met. Is there something that would work like this in the standard library:

```
copy_until(it, istream_iterator<char>(), ostream_iterator<char>(cout), [](const unsigned char i){ return isalpha(i); })
```

If I have to roll something I can I was just hoping for some magic that I haven't been able to figure out.

**EDIT:**

The behavior I would expect from my made up `copy_until` function is:

```
while(it != istream_iterator<char>()) {
    if(!isalpha(static_cast<unsigned char>(*it))) break;
    cout << *it++;
}
```

Comment: you mean like [`copy_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy)? or some kind of `find` algo that finds 1 past element that meets condition so you can copy a range?

Comment: @EdChum No, `copy_if` continues to copy even if the condition was not true. I want something that halts the copy when the condition is violated, I've edited to clarify.

Comment: Just for terminology, this problem asises with all **input iterators**, of which `std::istream_iterator<char>` is an example.

Comment: @PeteBecker Yes, I'd initially had just written input iterator, but the answers make it clear that even with a specific input iterator example people misunderstood the question :( If you think it would be helpful I can edit it back into the question.

Comment: @JonathanMee -- no change needed; just adding some information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm Provides a very helpful reference to all the algorithms available in C++ (not just those in the *Algorithm Library* but also the *Numeric*, *Memory*, and *CStd Libraries*.) Of those the following are copying algorithms, that is they take Input Iterator(s), Output Iterator(s), and lambda(s) as arguments:

- [`copy_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) "Copies the elements in the range, defined by [`first`, `last`)... Only copies the elements for which the predicate `pred` returns true"
- [`transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) "Applies the given function to a range and stores the result in another range."
- [`remove_copy_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove_copy) "Copies elements from the range [`first`, `last`), to another range beginning at `d_first`, omitting the elements which satisfy specific criteria"
- [`replace_copy_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace_copy) "Copies the all elements from the range [`first`, `last`) to another range beginning at `d_first` replacing all elements satisfying specific criteria with `new_value`"
- [`unique_copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique_copy) "Copies the elements from the range [`first`, `last`), to another range beginning at `d_first` in such a way that there are no consecutive equal elements... Elements are compared using the given binary predicate `p`"
- [`partition_copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition_copy) "Copies the elements from the range [`first`, `last`) to two different ranges depending on the value returned by the predicate `p`. The elements, that satisfy the predicate `p`, are copied to the range beginning at `d_first_true`. The rest of the elements are copied to the range beginning at `d_first_false`"
- <strike>[`merge`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge)</strike> Requires a 2<sup>nd</sup> input range
- <strike>[`set_difference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference)</strike> Requires a 2<sup>nd</sup> input range
- <strike>[`set_intersection`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection)</strike> Requires a 2<sup>nd</sup> input range
- <strike>[`set_symmetric_difference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_symmetric_difference)</strike> Requires a 2<sup>nd</sup> input range
- <strike>[`set_union`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_union)</strike> Requires a 2<sup>nd</sup> input range
- [`adjacent_difference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_difference) "Computes the differences between the second and the first of each adjacent pair of elements of the range [`first`, `last`)... Differences are calculated using the given binary function `op`"
- [`partial_sum`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sum) "Computes the partial sums of the elements in the subranges of the range [`first`, `last`) and writes them to the range beginning at `d_first`... To sum up the elements, the second version uses the given binary function `op`."
- [`exclusive_scan`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/exclusive_scan) "Computes an exclusive prefix sum operation using `binary_op` for the range [`first`, `last`)"
- [`inclusive_scan`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/inclusive_scan) "Computes an inclusive prefix sum operation using `binary_op` for the range [`first`, `last`)"
- [`transform_exclusive_scan`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform_exclusive_scan) "Transforms each element in the range [`first`, `last`) with `unary_op`, then computes an exclusive prefix sum operation using `binary_op` over the resulting range"
- [`transform_inclusive_scan`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform_inclusive_scan) "Transforms each element in the range [`first`, `last`) with `unary_op`, then computes an inclusive prefix sum operation using `binary_op` over the resulting range"

Because the lambda is only used to modify the 1:1 assignment of the range [`first`, `last`) to `d_first`; `transform`, `replace_copy_if`, and all of the *Numeric Library* algorithms are unhelpful (`adjacent_difference`, `partial_sum`, `exclusive_scan`, `inclusive_scan`, `transform_exclusive_scan`, and `transform_inclusive_scan`.)

- **If after the lambda condition was met the remainder of the range [`it`, `istream_iterator<char>()`) was to be directly copped to a 2<sup>nd</sup> output iterator, `partition_copy` would solve your problem**
- **If after the lambda condition was met the remainder of the range [`it`, `istream_iterator<char>()`) was to be iterated over by a function, this function could be called on each value after the condition was met by `copy_if` (or `remove_copy_if` or `unique_copy`)**
- But in the general case, the answer to your question is the standard algorithms do not provide a "copy_until" so you'll need to use your `while`-loop

Answer (score 8):

Just for completness, since the standard provides no out of box solution, thats my solution:

```
template<class _InIt, class _OutIt, class _Pr>
inline void copy_until (_InIt _First, _InIt _Last, _OutIt _Dest, _Pr _Pred) {
  while ((_First != _Last) && _Pred(*_First)) {
    *_Dest++ = *_First++;
  }
}
```

And that's how I use it:

```
copy_until(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(is),
           std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(),
           std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(os), 
           [] (char c) { return <some usefull condition here> });
```

For instance to read a string with only alnum characters from an input stream:

```
std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& is, std::string& n) {
  std::ostringstream str;
  copy_until(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(is),
             std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(),
             std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(str), 
             std::isalnum);
  n = str.str();
  return is;
}
```

Comment: Not bad... I think I'd still go with the `while` loop just for clarity, but this is usable.

Answer (score 3):

There is no copy until out of the box. Since you are copying from istream there is no other option but to use the loop with the break statement in it.

Comment: Doesn't work with an `istream_iterator`, which is what the question is specifically about.

Comment: @JonathanMee, oh, you reversed the `copy` arguments in your mock function. I thought you are copying from it to `cout`, as `copy` args do. I suggest you change the arguments to avoid confusion. In this case, just use loop.

Comment: I'm not certain I understand what you mean, the legal range is [`it`, `istream_iterator<char>()`) which are my first 2 arguments and the output iterator is `ostream_iterator<char>(cout)` which is my third argument, followed by my lambda. This follows the function definition of say `copy_if` or any of the conditional copy algorithms.

Comment: @JonathanMee, ok, I misread it again. IYou are copying from some istream to cout. got it.

Comment: Heh, seems like misunderstanding was common on this question. It just seems like there should be something in the standard to do this.

Answer (score -1):

`copy_until` could be realized with `std::find_if`, and `std::copy`.

Using the same structure as redleg, the algorithm could first search for the terminator, and then copy the range.

```
template <class _InIt, class _OutIt, class _Pr>
inline void copy_until(_InIt _First, _InIt _Last, _OutIt _Dest, _Pr _Pred) {
    _InIt _posTerm = std::find_if(_First, _Last, _Pred);
    std::copy(_First, _posTerm, _Dest);
}
```

The template requires `<algorithm>`, and `<iterator>`.

Here is an example how to use it:

```
std::vector<int> source = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
std::vector<int> dest {};

copy_until(source.begin(),source.end(), 
           back_inserter(dest),[](int c) {return c == 5;});
```

with the output:

```
source: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
dest  : 1 2 3 4
```

Beacuse `std::copy` is defined to copy till last, but excluding last or in other terms `[first,last)`, the position of `find_if` is not copied.

In case you need an inclusive until, meaning `[first,last]`, we need to do some more checking. If the Terminator is at the `end()` the iterator should not be advanced.

```
template <class _InIt, class _OutIt, class _Pr>
inline void copy_until(_InIt _First, _InIt _Last, _OutIt _Dest, _Pr _Pred)
{
    _InIt _posTerm = std::find_if(_First, _Last, _Pred);
    if (_posTerm != _Last ) { _posTerm++; }
    std::copy(_First,_posTerm,_Dest);
}
```

the previous example would now output:

```
source: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
dest  : 1 2 3 4 5
```